# Как получить ID пользователя после его выхода из беседы ВК

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Не могу получить user id пользователя после его выхода с беседы. Help.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

token_vk = 'zxc'
autorizate = vk_api.VkApi(token = token_vk)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(autorizate, group_id = 1234567890)
vk = autorizate.get_api()

while True:
  for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text'):
      id = event.chat_id
      
      if #пользователь вышел/его кикнули:
        vk.message.send('message = 'Пользователь {id пользователя} вышел из беседы.', random_id = get_random_id(), chat_id = 123')
```

Comment: При событиях приходит json, у которого есть путь `['object']['message']['action']`. `action` в себе содержит поле `type`. Когда участник покидает беседу (сам или исключили), этот `type` равен `chat_kick_user`.

Comment: А можно пример через код пожалуйста? :(

Answer (score 0):

Держи

```
def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and (action := event.obj['message'].get('action')):
            if action['type'] == 'chat_kick_user':
                vk.messages.removeChatUser(
                    chat_id=event.chat_id,
                    user_id=action['member_id'],
                )
```

Comment: Метод removeChatUser удаляет пользователя из беседы. Мне не нужно его удалять через бота, мне нужно отслеживать кикнули его или нет. И не с конкретным пользователям, а со всеми участниками беседы.

Comment: @Yura, @Muxe1 ответил правильно, но с небольшим недочётом, после условия: `if action['type'] == 'chat_kick_user', просто напишите: `user_id=action['member_id']` и всё. Ну, и отправьте сообщение о выходе.

Comment: @Komedik в результате вашей правки получается некорректный код. Или проверяйте код перед правкой, или не правьте чужой код.

Comment: Да, похоже ошибся, извините. Сам занимаюсь довольно большим проектом, напутал